# In android, how to set the 2 small icons visible in the notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

In android notification, it's seam their is 3 different icons (see the picture below). I know how to set the large icon (via **setlargeicon**), however i don't know how to set the both 2 small icons as their is only one procedure **setSmallIcon** available.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the same `setSmallIcon` for both locations. However, you can also use [setColor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setColor(int)) to set the background color on the notification - that is how the lower icon gets the blue background.